# Whats the purpose of VM disk encryption in Azure?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM and and i encrypt my OS disk. Now everything functions as normal. I can see a small lock on the c:\ drive.

But the question is whats the real purpose of the encryption ? How does it protect the disks , in what way ? I mean another user that has access can come and rdp and still view the disk ?
So in what scenario is this of any use ?

How does it stop unauthorised access, I mean some one can take the disks , attach to a VM and they have the data ? (is that right?)

Also if i was to take a snapshot and create a new VM with these disks , will the encryption still be there ?

**UPDATE**

*Encrypting the OS disk ensures that data remains inaccessible without the encryption key, deterring unauthorized access even if the disk is stolen*

You mention the data inaccessible if the disk is stolen , how does that work ?

So if the disk is encrypted on my Azure subscription via Key Vault entires that hold the encryption keys , does that mena that if i restore the snapshots on my tenant then it will work ?
Does it mean if the disks and snapshots are stolen and someone tries to restore the disks to a Vm then it wont work because it cant find the Key Vault keys on their tenant ?

Is that how it works?

Comment: None of what you say is correct. The data is encrypted using your own account, so no one other than you can access it, unless you give them your credentials. It stops unauthorized access by not allowing anyone that does not have your user information from accessing it, just like every other form of encryption.

Comment: Ok taken on board. But I have a VM and on that vm are some services that run that need to access the c: drive , will that still work ?

Comment: Also I have a service running on a port  on the c:\ drive that others need to access from their browser , will they still be able to access it ?

Comment: Also what credentials , I thought it was a key vault ?

Comment: If those services are authenticated using your credentials, they should have access to the C drive.

Comment: If you have a service running on a port on the C:\ drive of your encrypted VM, others will still be able to access it as long as they have the necessary network access permissions and credentials to connect to the service.Disk encryption primarily protects the data stored on the disk from being accessed if the disk is stolen or accessed without proper authentication

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the purpose of VM disk encryption in Azure?

Encrypting the `OS disk` is to protect the data on the disk from unauthorized access. This process ensures that only users with the correct encryption key can access the data.

**Azure VM Encryption:**

[image]

When you encrypt the `OS disk`, it protects the data on the disk in several ways:

1. Encrypting the OS disk ensures that data remains inaccessible without the encryption key, deterring unauthorized access even if the disk is stolen
2. It adds an additional layer of security by preventing unauthorized access to data even if someone gains access to the VM through RDP
3. Encryption protects data integrity in snapshots used to create new VMs, ensuring that sensitive information remains secure across instances

Reference:  [Azure Disk Encryption for Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-overview)

Comment: I have updated the question with more questions and a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a generic security question regarding encryption that is not really related to Azure VMs.

The purpose of disk encryption is to protect the data on the disk from unauthorized access, even if the disk is physically stolen or removed from the computer/server. Disk encryption uses a key to encrypt and decrypt every bit of data on the disk, making it unreadable without the correct key.
Disk encryption can protect the disks in different ways, depending on the type and level of encryption.

Disk encryption does not protect the disks from authorized users who have the correct key or password to access the disk. For example, if another user has the permission to remotely access the computer or the disk, they can still view the data on the disk, unless the data is also encrypted with a different key or password. Therefore, disk encryption should be used in combination with other security measures, such as strong passwords, user authentication, access control, firewall, antivirus, etc., to ensure the protection of the data on the disk.

You need to understand that Microsoft is always in control of the DEK. With BYOK/CMK, you can use a KEK to wrap the DEK, hence, taking control over the keys.

If you use Azure Disk Encryption with a key encryption key (KEK) stored in Azure Key Vault, you can restore the snapshots on your tenant as long as you have access to the same key vault and the same KEK. However, if the disks and snapshots are stolen and someone tries to restore them to a VM in another tenant, they will not be able to access the data without the KEK. The KEK is required to unwrap the encryption secrets that are stored in the snapshot metadata.

- https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topics/cryptography/disk-encryption-101/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-key-vault?wt.mc_id=MVP_323223